# When I use sudo to run a command, aren't the environment variables visible?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, script

```
$cat test
export var=value

$source ./test

$cat print.sh
echo $var

$chmod +x print.sh

$echo $var
value

$sudo ./print.sh
```

I get nothing.
I was expecting to see value.

What is going on?

Comment: Does `$ ./print.sh` (without sudo) shows `value` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to keep the environment with a sudo, use `sudo -E` that will preserve environment.

If you need to always preserve some of your environment variables, edit the sudoers file to add lines :

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        env_keep += "YOURVARIABLE OTHERVARIABLE YETANOTHER"
```